# Converting from 3.5 to 4.0 framework

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

we are trying to convert our web application from .net framework 3.5 to 4.0
The application contains a wcf project. will VS 2010 convert this project and update the service references in the web application automatically? or should i do it manually by updating every service reference?

Comment: I would just try on the copy of the solution rather than waiting for the answer here. This is very trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just back-up the project, then convert? That'll tell you how well it'll convert immediately afterwards, when you try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess VS2010 does it automatically..
But the target framework will still remain 3.5 if I'm not mistaken..

Answer (score 0):

Where did you create the service reference? VS2010 or VS2008

if you did it in VS2010 I wouldn't worry about updating it since VS2010 uses svcutil v4 to create the reference even if the target framework for the project was 3.5. If you dig into the code generated you can see it was generated with WCF 4 tools.